# Passar Paramento com Apas Duplas VBS

Tags: windows, vbs, vbscript

Como passar um parâmetro que tenha aspas duplas em vbs
`Atalho.Arguments = ""args.ext""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com duas aspas duplas, isso vai escapar as aspas e gerar o valor como `"args.ext"`.

```
Atalho.Arguments = """args.ext"""
```

Comment: perfeito! era exatamente isso que queria!